# Update branch without deleting pull request made from it

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and GitHub. I forked a repository and cloned it to my machine. Created a branch `fix-a-certain-issue`. I worked on this branch and pushed it back to `origin/fix-a-certain-issue` and then opened a PR. Two days later, the PR is reviewed and I am supposed to make changes to it. The problem is my `fix-a-certain-issue` is behind `upstream/master` by `x` commits. How do I update `fix-a-certain-issue` so that it is even with `upstream/master` without deleting/closing my PR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1. In your branch, do `git merge origin/master`. If you have merge conflicts, you need to resolve. You will have an additional commit created for merge
2. Alternatively, you can do `git rebase origin/master`. Here again you need to resolve conflicts if there are any. But you will not have the merge commit part of the history.
   Once you push the changes, the PR will be updated automatically. Only your changes should show up in the diff.